# Query hangs indefinitely - Postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

We had an issue in where a query would hang indefinitely with the inclusion of certain IDs in the last `WHERE IN` statement here:

```
SELECT 1
FROM items
WHERE id NOT IN (
                 SELECT items_id
                 FROM "items_attribute"
                 WHERE "items_attribute"."attribute_id" IN
                       (88376, 88354, 88380, 74984, 12983, 1205, 10931, 78061)
);
```

Those IDs that caused the hanging did not seem to present with any data anomaly. Do you see any issues with this query that would cause recursion or any potential issues? We seemed to resolve the issue by making the subselect `DISTINCT`. The select in question returns 164760 rows. There are no views here, only small indexed tables.

Explain:

```
Seq Scan on items (cost=2594.08..3816558214.87 rows=164034 width=0)
   Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Materialize  (cost=2594.08..25511.56 rows=139699 width=4)
           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on items_attribute  (cost=2594.08..24267.06 rows=139699 width=4)
                 Recheck Cond: (attribute_id = ANY ('{88376,88354,88380,74984,12983,1205,10931,78061}'::integer[]))
                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on items_attribute_attribute_id_index  (cost=0.00..2559.16 rows=139699 width=0)
                       Index Cond: (attribute_id = ANY ('{88376,88354,88380,74984,12983,1205,10931,78061}'::integer[]))
```

Thank you so much for taking a look!!

Comment: Is that the plan for the slow one or the fast one?  Whichever it is, please post the plan for the other one, too.  For the fast one, make it an `explain (analyze, buffers)`.

Comment: Rewrite your query using `SELECT 1 FROM items WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM items_attribute WHERE ... )`. `EXISTS` is faster than `IN`.

Comment: Is there concurrent access?

Comment: Whatever the problem is, there isn't enough information to solve it. Though I would try pietrops suggestion if for no other reason because it handles nulls and will be planned like an anti-join.

Answer (score -3):

Try dropping and recreating any indexes on items.id or items_attribute.attribute_id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. Both those fields are individually btree indexed. Do you think the sequential scan could be doing it? i.e should I look into how to make postgres use an index?

Comment: I have had queries fail (not hang) due to a corrupt index. I see you've got at least one called items_attribute_attribute_id_index.

Comment: I just want to chime in that I'm facing a problem that I think is similar here.  A query for dates between 1st and 10th works fine, but for dates between 1st and 11th fails.  I can do a different query for the 11th and such without a problem.  I finally noticed that the query plan for the hang is using an index scan, so I'm going to try rebuilding the index to see if it might be corrupt